# Selenium code not executed after driver.get (browser is IE)

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium. My code works fine with Chrome webdrive. However, when I switch to IE webdrive, my code does not execute after `drive.get`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r"C:\Drivers\IE_Driver\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")
print(driver.current_url)
print ("Test")
```

Comment: Does it throw any error? Which version of IE WebDriver are you using? It is recommend to use version 3.150.1 which can be downloaded in [this page](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/). Besides, if you're automating IE 11, you could set up your Test Environment as per the specification mentioned in [this article](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration).

Answer (score 1):

I have verified your code & its working without any issue.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r"C:\IEDriverServer.exe")

driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")

print(driver.current_url)

print ("Test")
```

**Output:**

[image]

I would suggest to Download IE Drivers based on your OS (Windows 32 or 64 bit) and then try once again

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration

you have to do the prerequisite steps mentioned there , expecially disabling the enhanced protection. I was able to reproduce your issue.

[image]

**uncheck the box for everything internet,local , trustred and restricted**

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `set webdriver.IeOptions ignore_protected_mode_settings = True`, then `drive.get response`.